# Flask's url_for raises TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to generate a url for my details route and redirect to it.  I call `redirect(url_for(details))`, but get `TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/search_process')
def search():
    return redirect(url_for(details))

@app.route('/details')
def details():
    return 'details'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Rabbit/PycharmProjects/Final_Project/Final_Project.py", line 59, in search
    return redirect(url_for(details))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 268, in url_for
    if endpoint[:1] == '.':

TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the endpoint name, a string, to `url_for`.

```
return redirect(url_for('details'))
```